# Spurious white line above SVG in HTML markup

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg

In a mobile webapp that I am currently working on I want to use a header bar with a "wavy" bottom edge.  My approach to doing this is shown below.

```css
:root {
  --lx-white: #fff;
  --lx-fontPrimary: calc(12px + ((100vh - 500px)/500)*4);
  --lx-fontSecondary: calc(10px + ((100vh - 500px)/500)*4);
  --lx-Z0: 0;
  --lx-Z1: 1000;
  --lx-small-margin: 0.5rem;
  --lx-std-margin: 1rem;
  --lx-mid-margin: 1.5rem;
  --lx-big-margin: 2rem;
  --lx-small-pad: 0.5rem;
  --lx-std-pad: 1rem;
  --lx-big-pad: 2rem;
  --lx-std-radius: 8px;
  --lx-small-radius: 4px;
  --lx-big-radius: 12px;
  --lx-orange: #de6520;
  --lx-light-orange: #e68a55;
  --lx-white: white;
  --lx-bg-white: #f2f4f3;
  --lx-light-grey: #999999;
  --lx-fontSize-minus1: 0.9rem;
  --lx-fontSize-plus1: 1.1rem;
  --lx-fontSize-plus2: 1.2rem;
  --lx-fontSize-plus3: 1.3rem;
  --lx-fontSize-plus5: 1.5rem;
  --lx-fontFace-main: 'arial';
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: var(--lx-fontFace-main);
}

.fullScreen {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.scrollBox {
  position: relative;
}

.scrollContainer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -100px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: var(--lx-std-pad);
  z-index: var(--lx-Z0);
}

.flexCentered {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btnBox {
  background-color: var(--lx-bg-white);
  padding-bottom: var(--lx-std-pad);
}

button {
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: var(--lx-std-radius);
  background-color: var(--lx-orange);
  padding: var(--lx-std-pad);
  color: var(--lx-white);
}

.mainButton {
  font-size: var(--lx-fontSize-plus1);
  font-weight: bold;
}

.wideBtn {
  min-width: 60vw !important;
}

#tosScreen {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  grid-template-rows: 12vh 1fr 12vh;
}

#tosHeader {
  z-index: var(--lx-Z1);
}

#tosH1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: var(--lx-std-pad);
  font-size: var(--lx-fontSize-plus3);
  text-align: left;
  background-color: var(--lx-light-orange);
  color: var(--lx-white);
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

#tosFooter {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  z-index: var(--lx-Z1);
  padding-top: var(--lx-big-pad);
}
```

```html
<div class='fullScreen' id='tosScreen'>
  <header id='tosHeader'>
    <h1 id='tosH1'>Terms of Service</h1>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 375 56" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:2"><path style="fill:#e68a55" d="M-.171-.059h374.734v36.17H-.171z" transform="matrix(1.00071 0 0 1 .172 .059)"/><path d="M375 148.52v8.36c-33.3 9.15-90 18.28-165.06 6.51-83.31-13.08-164.87-3.78-209.94 3.87v-54.17c.5 6.13.78 9.61.78 9.61s65 38.28 174.47 18.69c84.12-15.06 166.21-.45 199.75 7.13Z" style="fill:#de6520;fill-rule:nonzero" transform="translate(0 -113.031)"/></svg>
  </header>
  <div class='scrollBox'>
    <div class='scrollContainer' id='termsScroller'>
      &nbsp;
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer id='tosFooter'>
    <div class='btnBox flexCentered'>
      <button id='btnContinue' class='wideBtn mainButton'>Continue</button>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

When I view this in Chrome and in Opera with the display toggled to simulate a mobile screen I see a faint white line separating the header and the SVG below it.  This does not appear to happen on Edge.  I can't be bothered testing this on Firefox - not relevant to my project anyway.

What is causing this?

---

[image: White line highlighted]

In the screenshot above I have attempted to highlight the location of the line in the dotted blue rectangle

Comment: Your snippet looks fine in WIndows Chrome... You can always move your svg 1px up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the is the space you are referring to - if so it is caused by the svg being an inline element. Try changing it to block - and the space should be gone

```
svg {
  display: block;
}
```

[image]

If related to shape rendering - try adding `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` to the first path in the svg

```
<path 
  style="fill:#e68a55" 
  d="M-.171-.059h374.734v36.17H-.171z" 
  transform="matrix(1.00071 0 0 1 .172 .059)" 
  shape-rendering="crispEdges"
/>
```

**Edit** - I ran a few optimizations using [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) to simplify the shapes - maybe that will work too

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 375 56">
  <path fill="#E68A55" d="M0 0h375v36.2H0z"/>
  <path fill="#DE6520" d="M375 35.5v8.3c-33.3 9.2-90 18.3-165 6.6-83.4-13.1-165-3.8-210 3.8V9.1l.8.6s65 38.2 174.4 18.7c84.2-15.1 166.3-.5 199.8 7Z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I have edited my question - the screenshot shows the exact location of the white line.  As I mention in the question: this does not turn up except in the mobile screen simulators on Chrome and Opera.  Edge has now issues, not even with mobile screen simulation turned on.

Comment: Ah, then I think it has to do with shape rendering (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering) try adding shape-rendering="crispEdges" to the svg and see if it solves it :-)

Comment: Thinking about it - maybe only add it to the first path of the svg (it will pixelate the waves if added to all) - I've updated the answer

Comment: Perfect answer! - adding `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` to the first path; the rectangular bit above the wave; fixed it.  As you had guessed having `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` causes the wave bottom to be unacceptably pixelated

Comment: Great :-) I also added an optimized version to the answer - if it could help

Comment: Thank you for the more compact SVG - I had put my SVG through SVGOMG but clearly you have done a better job.  For the benefit of anyone wishing to copy what I have done here: another way to get round this issue is to `position:relative` the `h1`, give it an `::after` pseudo child, absolutely position the latter, `z-index` it so it sits on top, give it a little height, say `left:0;right:0;top:100%;bottom:-5px` and a suitable background color. This places it above any pesky rendering artefacts you might get from SVG